# How to load the full object graph of an entity when the child entity has a composite key for a many to many relationship?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a customer that can have many licenses and each license can have many products

```
    public class License
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Customer? Customer { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public List<LicenseProduct> LicenseProducts { get; set; } = new();
}

    public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public LicenseType LicenseType { get; set; } = LicenseType.Monthly;
    public Version Version { get; set; } = Version.Full;
    public List<LicenseProduct> LicenseProducts { get; set; } = new();
}

    public class LicenseProduct
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int LicenseId { get; set; }
    public Product? Product { get; set; }
    public License? License { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "decimal(18,2)")]
    public decimal BaseDiscount { get; set; }
}
```

Configuring the composite key in the data context

```
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<LicenseProduct>().HasKey(tc => new { tc.ProductId, tc.LicenseId });
        modelBuilder.Entity<LicenseProduct>()
            .HasOne(l => l.License)
            .WithMany(p => p.LicenseProducts);
        modelBuilder.Entity<LicenseProduct>()
            .HasOne(l => l.Product)
            .WithMany(p => p.LicenseProducts);
    }
```

Requesting data from the database

```
    public async Task<ServiceResponse<Customer>> GetAsync(int customerId)
{
    var response = new ServiceResponse<Customer>()
    {
        Data = await _dataContext.Customers
                .Include(c => c.Contacts)
                .Include(n => n.CustomerNotes)
                .Include(l => l.Licenses)
                .ThenInclude(log => log.LicenseLogs)
                .Include(l => l.Licenses)
                .ThenInclude(p => p.LicenseProducts)
                .Include(l => l.Licenses)
                .ThenInclude(u => u.Users)
                .ThenInclude(ws => ws.Workstations)
                .ThenInclude(id => id.TargetIds)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(i => i.Id == customerId)
    };

    response.Success = response.Data != null ? true : false;

    return response;
}
```

The Product in each LicenseProduct is null.  All other entities are loaded correctly.

BTW, I'm new to EF and databases in general so any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add one more include to the `Product` from the `LicenseProduct`.

```cs
Data = await _dataContext.Customers
    .Include(c => c.Contacts)
    .Include(n => n.CustomerNotes)
    .Include(l => l.Licenses)
    .ThenInclude(log => log.LicenseLogs)
    .Include(l => l.Licenses)
    .ThenInclude(p => p.LicenseProducts)
    .ThenInclude(p => p.Product)
```